# What type of squash/gourd is this?

Tags: squash, cucurbits

I planted what was supposed to be a gourd and it has given a few of these fruits from small flowers (similar to cucumber) that have reached around 20cm long and about 2kg.

Any idea what they are?

[image]

Comment: In addition - if whoever you got the seed/plant from have some other variety of squash/gourd/pumpkin/melon/cucumber they hybridize very very easily and the fruit tend to look like a cross of the two plants. I would guess that this is a cross between courgette/zucchini and something else, possibly a gourd.

Comment: Thanks Joe and Bob. The more I observe it, the more I think it is a kind of Canteloupe or Rock melon. I was tricked my the smooth texture, but after some research it appears that some varieties start off with a dark green color and smooth texture.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a tutame or Spaghetti squash possibly.
There's also, "Round Zucchini" with the melon look